# Best mail library for Java web applications

Tags: java, email

I am investigating on the best free mail library to use for Java web applications. It is something with more support and easy to use. If it's complex but would be justified by its great features it might do.

Have any suggestions?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

"Best" is subjective, especially since you didn't specify any particular features you may be looking for.

With that said, here's a couple to get you started:

1. [Simple Java Mail](http://www.simplejavamail.org) - built on top of JavaMail, simplifies API to produce a correct emails
2. [Commons Email](http://commons.apache.org/email/) - built on top of JavaMail, simplifies certain commonly used scenarios.
3. [Spring Email integration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mail.html) (only if you're using Spring already)

javaee.github curates a comprehensive list with many more:

- https://javaee.github.io/javamail/ThirdPartyProducts

Oracle has a curated list as well, although the lists are suspiciously similar:

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/third-party-136965.html

Comment: Any of those mail sdk supports adding smtp tag  to emails?

Comment: @Aminul What is an SMTP tag in an email?

Answer (score 5):

JavaMail is the standard, but it is only a client, so you need to have a separate e-mail service to send mail. [Asprin](http://github.com/masukomi/aspirin) is a good implementation of a server.

EDIT: Asprin is a send only e-mail server. You can't use it as a full fledged POP or IMAP server. It just sends e-mail without any further third party (such as an ISP's mail service) dependencies (other than an internet connection). Unlike JavaMail, which requires you to have an SMTP server available to send e-mail for you (like from your ISP). If you need a full e-mail server, that can provide pop and imap e-mail, take a look at [James](http://james.apache.org/).

[Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/third-party-136965.html) is a list of java mail options, although most, like JavaMail, are clients, not stand alone solutions.

Comment: You can use JavaMail to send mail via SMTP. See http://www.javacommerce.com/displaypage.jsp?name=javamail.sql&id=18274

Comment: @Brian, you don't understand the link. The link is saying you need an SMTP server provided by your ISP. With Asprin, you do not, it is its own SMTP server.

Comment: wow... Own SMTP server. Can aspirin also act as a IMAP server? If it can then that would really be great. That would complete my mail system.

Comment: James also has Mime4j which is a rather nice improvement for MIME vs. JavaMail

Answer (score 2):

[Simple Java Mail](http://www.simplejavamail.org) which is a wrapper around Java Mail api:

https://github.com/bbottema/simple-java-mail ([Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.simplejavamail/simple-java-mail))

Comment: Pretty interesting JavaMail had a lot of pitfalls around remembering to save the message, contents being mutable, all sorts of horrible stuff. At work we also found that wrapping it in a safety / convenience layer was the only way to make it nice to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Does the Sun Javamail API not work for you?

http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/

Comment: it works but i was kindda hoping for something more full blown