# sendmail analog in java?

Tags: java, sendmail

I want to be able to send email to arbitrary address without login and authentication. sendmail provides this functionality. Is there any java library that provides the same functionality?

If there are not, and it impossible to create it, please explain, why it's impossible.

If there are such libraries, please, provide a usage example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wish to check out this Question:

[Best mail library for Java web applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574116/best-mail-library-for-java-web-applications)

Aspirin is a send-only embeddable SMTP server for Java:

https://github.com/masukomi/aspirin

This should allow you to send emails without any need for authentication or login, all you need is (obviously) an internet connection.